# How to create multiple sqlalchemy connections to the same DB but with different credentials?

Tags: mysql, flask, sqlalchemy, flask-sqlalchemy

I have a `flask` application using `sqlalchemy`. Currently, I have something like this:

```
from flask import Flask
from flask.ext.sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy

app = Flask(__name__)
app.config['SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI'] = 'mysql+mysqldb://user1@localhost:3306'
db = SQLAlchemy(app)
```

The `user1` account has default timeouts for db queries. However, certain API calls are expected to take longer and I would like to add longer timeouts for those specific calls. For this purpose, I have another db user (`user2`) which is configured with longer timeouts. What is the most seamless way to deal with connections to the same db but with different credentials? Ideally, I'd like to have something like:

```
from flask import Flask
from flask.ext.sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy

app = Flask(__name__)
app.config['SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI'] = 'mysql+mysqldb://user1@localhost:3306'
db = SQLAlchemy(app)
app.config['SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI'] = 'mysql+mysqldb://user2@localhost:3306'
long_query_db = SQLAlchemy(app)
```

and use `long_query_db` for the longer db queries just like I used `db` before. Unfortunately, what actually happens is that the `app.config` is modified before the connections are created and, as a result, both `long_query_db` and `db` use the credentials for `user2`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Recently done this to talk to a postgresdb for login and another mysql db for accessing some data.

config.py

```
SQLALCHEMY_OUTER_DATABASE = "mysql+mysqlconnector://" + OUTER_LOGIN + ":" + OUTER_PASSWORD + "@" + OUTER_SERVER + ":" + OUTER_PORT + "/" + OUTER_DATABASE
SQLALCHEMY_BINDS = {
    'binds': SQLALCHEMY_OUTER_DATABASE
}
```

**init**.py

```
global db_outer = None
....


def create_app(config_name):
    db.init_app(app) # first db
    engine = create_engine(app.config['SQLALCHEMY_OUTER_DATABASE'], pool_recycle = 3600)
    db_outer = scoped_session(sessionmaker(bind=engine)) # second db
```